# How can I modify this code to make the search box include tags and meta

Tags: php, wp-query, filters, query, search

How can I modify this code to make the search box include tags and meta

I would like the search in same box

```
if($_GET['s'] && !empty($_GET['s']))
{
    $text = $_GET['s'];
}

if($_GET['type'] && !empty($_GET['type']))
{
    $type = $_GET['type'];
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    's' => $text,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: if you use an input with the name `post_type` then you don't need a new `WP_Query` or a special `$_GET['type']`, it'll automatically generate URLs with `post_type=xyz` in the URL that are picked up by WordPress. This also means that a lot of the existing answers will work for you (because you discard the main query and create a new `WP_Query` those existing answers might not work for you, and you've made your search pages twice as slow).

Comment: Also note that search is built to search posts, you'll need to be more specific about what you mean by meta and tags, e.g. are you searching for tags themselves and want to display a tag as a search item? Or do you mean posts in a tag that you've searched for? Searching meta will be _very_ slow/expensive, and get more expensive as you add more content to your site. There's also 2 bugs in your code, if `$_GET['type']` isn't set the `$type` variable is undefined, yet you use it in the array even if it's undefined, which will give you PHP warnings and notices. I see no search box code in the Q

Comment: no i need to search for post have custom meta

Comment: like any post have book meta will show in result